# Hentenna beam...is it possible?

Tags: antenna-theory, antenna-construction

I did a (Amateur Radio) search for 'hentenna' and got not one hit. So, to boldly go where no man has gone before, I want to explore the strange new world of creating a beam antenna with **Hentenna** DE, with a reflector, most likely being a non-driven version of itself, and, to save wire and space, Yagi-type directors (rods)...maybe six of them.
  This **Hengi** doesn't seem too different from a **Quagi**; though, because the Hentenna is a long rectangle *perpendicular to its polarization*, **rod directors would be perpendicular to the Hentenna rectangles' long side**.
  I would approach it like the original 14ft., 2M Quagi. There are some "Hengi" beam antennas but they use 1 or 2 non-driven versions of the DE as directors. Would the **perpendicular** rods work like they do in Quagis and Yagis where they are more or less in the same plane as the DE? 
  http://n6nb.com/quagi.htm

[image]

There's also this:
  [image: With a hentenna instead of a skeleton slot.]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me combine the following statements of your question

> I want to explore (the strange new world of creating a beam antenna)
>
> to boldly go where no man has gone before
>
> Would the perpendicular rods work like they do in Quagis and Yagis where they are more or less in the same plane as the DE?

I would take the following approach:

- Figure out why you want to do this, e.g. extra forward-gain, extra FB-ratio and write it down, compared to a much simpler design (such as a vertical yagi with the same lenght/elements) call this your "success criteria"
- Get a freeware (or paid for) antenna modelling program, there are various, such as [4NEC2](http://www.qsl.net/4nec2/?) or [EZNEC](https://www.eznec.com/), and familiar yourself with the workings. There are others as well, these are the two which simply jump to mind for me.
- Model your design in the program, experiment with element positions, size, height, length, until you have a good idea if you can get close to your "success criteria"
- Once happy with the modelling, build your design, and test.
- If you want you can build a reference antenna (such as a yagi) and compare the two antenna's.

Lastly I would advice: have some fun, and enjoy the modelling and building.

To answer your question:
I have no idea if your perpendicular rods work in the way you propose. I could not find any reference material, nor do I have experience with such. However as your question indicates, this is more an experiment for you then a theoretical question.

Saying that; there is an article describing a "Hentenna Beam" but slightly different than you propose. You can find this [here](http://www.hamuniverse.com/n5nns4elhentenna.html). It is not very scientific, but it might help you with your endeavours.

An interesting read is an article about an "Hentenna with Reflectors" which might help you starting while adding elements to your design. You can find that [here](http://www.qsl.net/dk7zb/Quadlong/Hentenna.htm)

Have fun exploring and experimenting !

Comment: I have avoided trying to learn a modeling program because my memory is getting so bad. i did run across a simpler than most prog that was mm**m*m like mminimac or something I have a note of it somewhere. I've seen the articles that you suggest but there is more out there. (The 'reflector' page = wow.) The idea I have is so close to the original Quagi that it will probably be pretty similar, so I thought I'd see if anyone else has tried something like it or could speculate. The hentenna is a bit odd. BTW Forward gain is the quest. Simplex with civilization. Thanks. @Edwin van Mierlo

Comment: This is a great answer, Edwin!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it works. I have constructed a 2m double hentenna (REF and DE), double boom unit, with 6 director elements on each boom out front of the loops. So, it's sort of a combo of the drawing and the photo above. The directors are all bent/crooked (6AWG) and misaligned; nothing has been tested or modeled yet. From inside my cabin in a little valley...it's amazing.